# Laravel : artisan command not generating complete auto generated code

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I started to learn through a tutorial for learning Laravel 5.
https://tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-hello-world

I followed the steps

when I run the command : `php artisan make:controller Hello`

I am getting just the base code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class Hello extends Controller
{
    //
}
```

However the tutorial specify the auto-generated code with some functions as well inside the class.

It says the auto-generated code is,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class Hello extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I could not figure out what configuration changes need to be updated or I am missing something very basic for this framework to start with, I tried to reinstall the application again and the same issue happened again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tutorial looks a little dated. In Laravel 5.2, the command was updated to generate a plain controller by default.

To generate a "resource" controller, as shown in the tutorial, you now need to pass the "--resource" flag:

```
php artisan make:controller Hello --resource
```

Comment: Thanks ... So any good resource to learn the updated version (apart form documentation as ref) which teach with a complete project or its good to go with this itself, because it will be good to learn right than creating lot of misconception at the end?

Comment: @atjoshi One of the best resources for learning Laravel is Laracasts. There is a lot of great free content on there, and not just on Laravel. You'll probably want to start with the Learning Laravel from Scratch series, which is updated every release and is always free: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017

Answer (score 0):

the Artisan command you are looking for is:

```
php artisan make:controller UserController --resource
```

You could find all information about Controllers in the official documentation: 
[Laravel Controller documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers)

Or Google for information but specify your Laravel version